# Prove that for each $n$, there are $n$ consecutive integers, each of which is divisible by a perfect square larger than $1$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove that for each positive integer $n$, there are $n$ consecutive integers, each of which is divisible by a
perfect square larger than $1$.

Comment: This kind of stuff is obvious from the CRT. Why should I want to prove it?

Comment: @Marcvanleeuwen you do not simply argue with the commandments of our lord

Comment: @alex i am looking for problems like the one you posted;where can i find these ?

Comment: @Ben Stokes The OP hasn't logged back in for over 3 years but this particular question can be found in Jones Elementary number theory, chapter 3 number 19, with answers in the back. Similar questions are also in Burton Elementary number theory.

Comment: Thank you very much @user135711

Answer (score 13):

Consider the system of congruences
$x\equiv 0\pmod{2^2}$, $x\equiv -1\pmod{3^2}$, $x\equiv -2\pmod{5^2}$, and so on up to $x\equiv -(n-1)\pmod{p_{n-1}^2}$. (Here $p_0,p_1,\dots,p_{n-1}$ are the first $n$ primes.)

This system has a solution $x$, by the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Any such  $x$ is divisible by $2^2$, and $x+1$ is divisible by $3^2$, and so on.